# Javascript form redirect returns error

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sure this must be a simple fix, but I'm not sure what's going wrong. I'm looking to create a form that redirects depending on the selection of multiple fields.

My coding is as follows:

```
<form onsubmit="return setAction()" method="post" action="">
<div class="row">
<label for="FormCtrl_1">Where are you going?</label>
<select id="FormCtrl_1" name="FormCtrl_1">
  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
</select>
<select id="FormCtrl_2" name="FormCtrl_2">
  <option value="Business">Business</option>
  <option value="Pleasure">Plesure</option>
</select>
<select id="FormCtrl_3" name="FormCtrl_3">
  <option value="1">1 Day</option>
  <option value="2">2 Day</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<input value="Submit" type="submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

With the js:

```
function setAction() {
var country = document.getElementById("FormCtrl_1").value;
var reason = document.getElementById("FormCtrl_2").value;
var days = document.getElementById("FormCtrl_3").value;

if (country === "Afghanistan" && reason === "Business" && days === "1") 
{
    window.location = "https://google.com";
}

if (country === "Afghanistan" && reason === "Business" && days === "2") 
{
    window.location = "https://facebook.com";
}

return false; }
```

Comment: Please tell us what error you are experiencing.

Comment: Running it in a jsbin I get a 405 error: https://jsbin.com/vahoxuhewe/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Pls edit your question to update it with the relevant information.